# Chrome for Android reloading from cache after app is killed

Tags: android, ajax, google-chrome, breeze

I have a single-page web application which pulls in data via ajax calls to my web service (using breeze.js). The app loads data when first loaded and again when it receives notification to update via a connected web socket to the web service, i.e another browser session has made some changes.

Now, if Chrome is sent to the background with the page open and I modify data via say a desktop browser. The page receives the ping via web sockets and makes the ajax request getting the new data which I can see in Chrome if I bring it to the foreground. If I *kill* Chrome (swiping it off the multi-task menu, or just waiting for Android to kill it) and then make another edit in the desktop session. When I open it again, the page seemingly reloads (progress bar moves across with a delay until the page appears) and the initial ajax call is made (my loading spinner is shown) but *old* data is retrieved without the recent edit.

From my understanding, Chrome is loading a cached version of the page. This seems to include a cached result of the Ajax call. How do I ensure fresh data is retrieved from the server query and not stale cached data? I don't think even the web socket connection is even resumed because that too is getting cached data back, hence no further edits are seen. It seems the only solution is to reload the page but that's a pretty lousy experience.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to ensure all Breeze ajax requests disabled caching.

```
breeze.config.getAdapterInstance("ajax").defaultSettings = { cache: false };
```